# Prevent array_merge from merging an array if one of the specified argument is not an array

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

I want array_merge to merge only when the argument specified is an array else skip that argument.

Below is the code,

```
<?php

$mergedArray = array();
$a = array('Hello');
$b = array('Hi');
$c = 'World';
$mergedArray = array_merge($mergedArray, $a, $b, $c);
print_r($mergedArray);

?>
```

For the above code, I get a warning that `$c` is not an array.
I know that converting it into an array will fix the issue,

```
$mergedArray = array_merge($mergedArray, $a, $b, (array)$c);
```

But, `$c can be an array or a string`, and if it a string I don't want to include it as a parameter in my array_merge, if it an array I want it to be included. Is there any direct method in php to do it, or do I need to write it in if-else statement.

EDIT:
It doesn't make a difference if I include an empty array by checking `is_array($c)`. But if I have to implode that result using a delimiter then it will cause an issue,

Modified code,

```
<?php

$mergedArray = array();
$a = array('Hello');
$b = array('Hi');
$c = 'World';
$mergedArray = array_merge($mergedArray, $a, $b, is_array($c) ? $c : []);
$result = implode(' | ', $mergedArray);
print_r($mergedArray);

?>
```

Now for the above code, `in case of an empty array`, I will `get | at the end of $result` which I don't want.

Comment: `$mergedArray = array_merge($mergedArray, $a, $b, is_array($c) ? $c : []);`

Comment: use if or `array_merge(... array_filter('is_array', [$a, $b. $c]))`

Comment: https://eval.in/1047372

Comment: @RajMalhotra ? - https://eval.in/1047386

Comment: @splash58 Works bud...thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `is_array` function to check if a variable is an array or not.

```
$mergedArray = array_merge($mergedArray, $a, $b, is_array($c) ? $c : array());
```

If `$c` is an array, combine it. If not, just combine with empty array which doesn't affect the result.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <?php
   $mergedArray = array();
   $a = array('Hello');
   $b = array('Hi');
   $c = 'World';
   if (is_array($c)) {
     $mergedArray = array_merge($mergedArray, $a, $b, $c);
   } else {
     $mergedArray = array_merge($mergedArray, $a, $b);
   }
   print_r($mergedArray);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check if it is an array before merging it.

```
<?php
$mergedArray = array();
$a = array('Hello');
$b = array('Hi');
$c = 'World';

if (!is_array($c))
{
    $mergedArray = array_merge($mergedArray, $a, $b, array($c));
}

print_r($mergedArray);
?>
```